# How to extract all column and value from pyspark row?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

i am trying to extract all columns and value respectively from the below data frame row?

```
+--------+----------+-----+----+-----+-----------+-------+---+
|name    |department|state|id  |name | department| state | id|
+--------+----------+-----+----+-----+-----------+-------+---+
|James   |Sales     |NY   |101 |James|  Sales1   |null   |101| 
row=
[Row(name=James,department=Sales,state=NY,id=101,name=James,department=Sales1,state=None,id=101)]

tem_dict={}
for indext,value in enumerate(row):
    if row[index] in tem_dict:
         tem_dict[row[index]]=[row[index], value]
    else:
        tem_dict[row[index]]=value
```

But this not giving expected  result. since it has repeated element i want to combine the value of similar column and print it in a array as seen below

#expected

```
[{name:[james,james],departement:[Sales,Sales1],state:[NY,none],id:[101,101]}]
```

Or any way to do with rdd?
Any solution to this?

Comment: Adhi, the problem IMO is you are one list not deep enough, let me give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

```
>>> row

[Row(name=James,department=Sales,state=NY,id=101,name=James,department=Sales1,state=None,id=101), Row(...), Row(...), etc]
```

In that case to get what you expect I'd do:

```
tem_dict={}
for inner_row in row:
  for key, val in inner_row.asDict().items():
    if tem_dict.get(key, None) is None:
      tem_dict[key] = [val]
    else:
      tem_dict[key].append(val)

print(tem_dict)
```

Comment: Hello @scr, thanks for responding. By the way, the above approach not fetching all repeated columns and value in to the respective dictionary. as i mentioned, each row has repeated columns.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "repeated columns". Could you give an example?

Comment: These are total columns avaialble in the df
name    |department|state|id  |name | department| state | id

Comment: or is there any other way to do with rdd.map

Comment: Oh so you have state twice? Can't you just rename the second column to `state_2`?

Comment: the problem is i am not getting the column name in the result.. its only giving the value